# Data feed from Google Docs API

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, google-docs-api

I am trying to use the [Google Docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Docs) API to get spreadsheet data as XML, and eventually JSON data. I have put the URL (http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Aizy-VIdLC0QdDNNRkpfVncxQzZRNG9fMVhueXVMenc/1/private/values) in my browser, and I get the data, even when not logged in to Google.

When I try with jQuery Ajax, I get the "page not found" error.

```
$.get('http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Aizy-VIdLC0QdDNNRkpfVncxQzZRNG9fMVhueXVMenc/1/private/values', function(data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

I am guessing that same origin policy might be the cause of the Ajax error, so I tried with PHP, but I get the error.

```
echo file_get_contents("http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Aizy-VIdLC0QdDNNRkpfVncxQzZRNG9fMVhueXVMenc/1/private/values");
```

I am aiming to get the Google Docs spreadsheet data into a JSON object for use on a webpage.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It gives "not found" for me in a browser too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be logged in in order to be able to retrieve the spreadsheet data.

Visiting [http://spreadsheet.google.com/.../private/values](http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0Aizy-VIdLC0QdDNNRkpfVncxQzZRNG9fMVhueXVMenc/1/private/values) while logged in results in a meaningful XML page. Trying to load the same page when not logged in, however, results in a "Page Not Found".

According to the response header from the JQuery response, the only cause of this error is not being logged in (shown below).

```
WWW-Authenticate: No credentials were included in your request.
```

See [The Protocol Guide](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) for the relevant documentation.

Comment: so you must be logged in as anyone to access the url, but you must be logged in. I don't want the user to log in, I just want my script to read data, and use it without the user being involved. Is this possible, I have looked through the Protocol guide, and it seems to be geared towards getting the end user to be logged in - which is not what I want.

Comment: @Billy - so log your application in via the API on the server side using AuthSub: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthSub.html

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you double-checked your URL string, the reason could be [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You cannot fetch data from a different domain due to browser's strict security policy.

If you want to get past this, you need to use a different approach, such as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

You can read more about how to implement JSONP in jQuery on the [Ajax documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).